# Meta Rep goes up or no

Tags: support, reputation, meta

When we vote ask answer etc on the meta site does our rep change at all? I noticed that on the main site my rep is higher then on the meta site. I am guessing this is because of caching right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing on meta influences your reputation.

The difference is because there is a delay for your "meta" profile to be updated with data from "parent" profile.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks Rarst. Makes sense